# select from one table, count from another where id's linked

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

heres my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select c.name, c.address, c.postcode, c.dob, c.mobile, c.email, 
                    count(select * from bookings where b.id_customer = c.id) as purchased, count(select * from bookings where b.the_date > $now) as remaining, 
                    from customers as c, bookings as b 
                    where b.id_customer = c.id
                    order by c.name asc");
```

you can see what i am trying to do, but im not sure how to write this query properly.

heres the error i get:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource

heres my mysql_fetch_assoc:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['purchased']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['remaining']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php   
}

?>
```

Comment: Does this work when executed from phpmyadmin or the CLI interface?

Comment: Please show how you did your `mysql_fetch_assoc()` query.

Comment: i added it to the original post...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try changing the likes of...

```
count(select * from bookings where b.id_customer = c.id)
```

...to...

```
(select count(*) from bookings where b.id_customer = c.id)
```

Answer (score 25):

Your query incorrectly uses COUNT, which has been covered by [@Will A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971153/select-from-one-table-count-from-another-where-ids-linked/5971251#5971251).

I would also like to suggest a possibly better constructed alternative, which, I think, reflects the same logic:

```
SELECT
  c.name,
  c.address,
  c.postcode,
  c.dob,
  c.mobile,
  c.email,
  COUNT(*) AS purchased,
  COUNT(b.the_date > $now OR NULL) AS remaining
FROM customers AS c
  INNER JOIN bookings AS b ON b.id_customer = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

Note: Normally you are expected to include all the non-aggregated SELECT expressions into GROUP BY. However MySQL supports [shortened GROUP BY lists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), so it's enough to specify the key expressions that uniquely identify all the non-aggregated data you are pulling. **Please avoid using the feature arbitrarily**. If a column not included in GROUP BY has more than one value per group, **you have no control** over which value will actually be returned when pulling that column **without aggregation**.