# mySQL - How to use a COUNT() statement in a JOIN

Tags: mysql

In a mySQL DB there is a table named `clients`. Each client row has a column `client_num`. To list all clients I simply use this statement.

```
SELECT * FROM clients
```

Now each client may have or may have not some numbers of `subclients` which is listed in a seperate table named `subclients` and referenced through the foreign key `client_num` in the table.

To find out how many subclient a client may have I can query the subclient table in a seperate call like this: Lets say we have a client with the `client_num` 254.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM subclients WEHRE sublicents.client_num = 254
```

So the query returns something like 0, 1, 2, 3 , n

In a `JOIN` I assume I have to do something like this :

```
SELECT 
  c.*,
  sc.????? 
FROM clients AS c
LEFT JOIN subclients AS sc ON sc.client_num = 254
```

But I do not know how to incorporate the count() statement in the JOIN for the amount of subclients. Also I do not know if LEFT JOIN is correct.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT :

I must add that I expect `all` rows to be returned from clients. The  additional returned column `COUNT(sc.client_num)` carries than the amount of subclients. In the Answer 2 below I get only those clients returned which have subclients. Clients which `do not` have subclients are `not` returned.  How to fix that ?

Comment: Left Join is fine, on the basis that you don't need to retrieve every `subclient` row and that not every client will have subclients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the count of all sub-clients for each client:

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    COUNT(sc.client_num) 
FROM clients AS c
LEFT JOIN subclients AS sc ON sc.client_num = c.client_num
WHERE c.client_num = 254 
GROUP BY sc.client_sum
```

**solution using a sub-select:**

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subclients WHERE client_num = clients.client_num) 
FROM clients 
WHERE client_num = 254
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4930a/8/1

Comment: Here I got a SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... for the right syntax to use near '*)

Comment: specifiy a column instead of the `*`.

Comment: I use LEFT JION and it seems to work. What is wrorg about it ? I had a mistake in my JOIN statement before. Now it returns the expected figures

Comment: In my opinion the condition on the LEFT JOIN is wrong like written in the question. Should it be `LEFT JOIN subclients AS sc ON sc.client_num = c.client_num`?

Comment: As far as I now this doesn't matter. Both is true. But I have another problem which I did not see before. Now the query returns only rows where subclients are available. All clients without a subclient are excluded. So finally I got only a third of the expectect total amount of clients in the list. I guess I did not mention that in my question. How to fix that problem ?

Comment: @ Sebastian Brosch - The `solution using a sub-select` works. Now I get all client rows back with the number of subclients for each client. The JOIN solution does not work as describe in my EDIT above. Whats the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I read from a similar query on Stack Overflow was to use a sub-select. If your only purpose of the join is to `Count` I would suggest that the join is unneeded. So that:

```
SELECT clients.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subclients 
WHERE subclients.client_num = clients.id ) AS numb FROM clients WHERE ....
```

And then for a row of clients, they will have a column `numb` which will be number of subclients that that client has.

A [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971251/3536236).