# mysql count rows from another table with a where clause

Tags: mysql

hi guys need some help regarding of

how can i count the rows from another table with a where clause

so i have two tables

the table student and the attendance table i want to count all the attendance table that correspond to the student

here is the table table student

[image]

here is for table attendance

[image]

i tried this but just fetch the student that have Attendance

```
SELECT student.StudentID, student.`Name`, COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) AS Total
FROM student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
where DateEntered between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-01' 
GROUP BY student.StudentID,student.`Name`
```

what i want to heppen is that fetch all the student and count the number of how many times he/she has Attendance. With A where DateEntered

[image]

Thank u for help.......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select from one table, count from another where id's linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971153/select-from-one-table-count-from-another-where-ids-linked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put condition in the left join clause :

```
SELECT student.StudentID, student.`Name`, COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) AS Total
FROM student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
    and DateEntered between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-01' 
GROUP BY student.StudentID,student.`Name`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could left join `student` on an aggregate query on attendance:

```
SELECT     s.StudentID, 
           s.Name,
           COALESCE(Total, 0) 
FROM       student s
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT StudentId, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM   attendance
            GROUP BY StudentId) ON s.StudentId = a.StudentId
WHERE      DateEntered BETWEEN '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-01'
```